# Meteor - New row based on collection value?

Tags: javascript, html, css, meteor, handlebars.js

I'm trying to create a result where if a value in the collection is specified such as "New Row" That I create a new  tag.

Problem is if I use a helper I can't wrap the Start DIV in a Handle bar helper function. Separately from the Child of that DIV.

```
        {{#each myPostImages}}
        New Row: {{#if newrow}}
        <div class="row postee">    
                        <div class="col-xs-8 middlePost">
                   <img src={{url}}>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>                      
        {{/if}}



        {{/each}}
```

What can I do to some time not output the  as sometimes I want the next value in the collection to be contained in the same row.....?

I'm trying to create this result:

```
        <div class="row postee">    
                <div class="col-xs-8 middlePost">
                   <img src={{url}}>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-8 middlePost">
                   <img src={{url}}>
                </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-8 middlePost">
                   <img src={{url}}>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>                      
        <div class="row postee">
                <div class="col-xs-8 middlePost">
                   <img src={{url}}>
                </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve, of the following way

your archive .httml

```
 <template name="myPost">    
       {{#each myPostImages}}
        New Row: 
          {{#if newrow this}}
             <div class="row postee">  
               {{#each this.url}}
                  <div class="col-xs-8 middlePost">
                      <img src={{this}}>
                  </div>
               {{/each}}
             </div>
          {{else}}
             ....
          {{/if}}
        {{/each}}
 </template>
```

Your archive .js

```
  Template.myPost.helpers({
       'newrow': function(newrow){
          // new row is this in your template, this contain all attributes,
          // you can return anything you want, remember that the condition 
          // if require true or false
          return ...
       },
       'myPostImages':function(){
          // return array of collection
          var model= Collection.find({}).fetch(); 
          // you can create an array in your new model 
          model.url= []; 
          return model;
       } 
    })
```

Comment: I probably didn't articulate my question in total clarity. Will update the question